# Failed to construct 'HTMLElement'

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element

I run `my-widget.js` through babel (es2015 preset) to produce `my-widget-es5.js`.  This causes an error with Polymer.

```
Class constructor PolymerElement cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new MyWidget (my-widget.js:##)
    at mw-widget.js [sm]:##
```

file structure

```
out
 |
 -- my-widget-es5.js
js
 |
 -- my-widget.js
html
 |
 -- my-widget.html
```

my-widget.html

```
<dom-module id="my-widget">
    <template>
        <script src="/out/my-widget-es5.js"></script>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

my-widget.js

```
class MyWidget extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
        return 'my-widget';
    }
}

customElements.define(MyWidget.is, MyWidget);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43002652/4600982) SO user @joncarlson:

You may find a solution by using the `custom-elements-es5-adapter.js` file proposed as a workaround by [Webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below. Just use the es5-bundled preset version and you should be ready to go. It will include conditional loading of the custom-elements-es5-adapter.json that @Supersharp mentioned.

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-json#builds