# Angular elements error . "Failed to construct 'HTMLElement ...'

Tags: angular, custom-element, stackblitz

I am trying out a very simple application on angular elements on stackblitz and I am getting the following issue.

> Error: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new'
>   operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

All I am trying to do is trying to display hello world. I didn't face any issue doing this on visual code locally, however, this issue comes up on stackblitz. Not sure I have to follow some additional steps on stackblitz in order for me to run this application. Appreciate any help on this.

Here is the link to the application on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-elements).

Comment: add this adapter  https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js

Comment: check this https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/475

Comment: nice it worked!. Thanks alot .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to construct 'HTMLElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845582/failed-to-construct-htmlelement)

Comment: @FatehMohamed, but how can I add the file to stackblitz?

Answer (score 9):

Downgrade `document-register-element` to `v1.8.1` solved it.

```
npm i document-register-element@1.8.1
```

Work for me.

Cr. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24390#issuecomment-396729418

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue, just change the `target` to `es6` or `es2015` in your tsconfig.json file. That will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's facing the issue, and wants to still target `ES5` (for IE compatibility or other reasons), another reasonable solution is to use the **web component ES5 adapter polyfills**.

```
# Install the package
npm install @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs --save-dev

# Then add the following line in Polyfills.ts
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js';
```

From [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24556#issuecomment-446844111) GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

With angular 8 having the target version as es2015 enables differential loading and will end up having different build files for es5 & es2015 versions.

If above is not required, ideal fix would be to downgrade the document-register-element@1.8.1.

Any version >=1.7.2 <=1.8.1 should be working.